# How to pass and access the array variable using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array $param and while giving Print_r, the output as follows,

```
 Array ( 
[pattern] => 
[status] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 4 )
)
```

I have to pass the status value to one function like,

```
function value($action, $param){
// want to use the value here
}
```

how can i get the value here. please help

Comment: `$param["status"]` …?

Comment: `print_r($param['status']);`

Comment: function value($action, $param['status']){ } is this correct

Comment: try this `function value($action, $param){
// want to use the value here
print_r($param['status']);
}`

Comment: Thanks .. it is printing . but i want to use the values dynamically like,  $status= $param['status']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass a multi-dimensional array as a parameter, simply pass the child array with the name of the parent (container array).

So if an array like

```
Array ( 
         [pattern] => 
         [status] => Array (
                             [0] => 0 
                             [1] => 4 
                           )
)
```

if you want both the elements of `status` to be passed into the function,pass the name of the array parent. (in this case, **param**)

```
function foo($x)
{
  echo "<pre>"; // just to make reading easy ;)
  print_r($x);
 }
```

The `function foo()` displays the contents passed into the function which you can use to see what's being passed.

so things like ***`foo($param['status'])`***
gives this :

```
Array( [0] => 0 [1]=> 4 )
```

and something like ***`foo($param['status'][1])`***
gives this :
    `4`