# arrays passed in functions - php

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have a question about the passing of multidimensionsal arrays in functions.

I have the following code (arrays), there are a few more arrays.

```
$product = array();
$product[] = array(
    'Category' => "Smartphone",
    'Seller' => "Apple",
    'Product' => "<img src='Bild_iPhone_8.JPG' alt='iPhone 8' height='130px' />",
    'Price' => 836,
    'Selection' => "Mark1"
);
$product[] = array(
    'Category' => "Smartphone",
    'Seller' => "Samsung",
    'Product' => "<img src='Bild_Galaxy_S8.JPG' alt='Galaxy S8' height='130px' />",
    'Price' => 649,
    'Selection' => "Mark2"
);
$product[] = array(
    'Category' => "Notebook",
    'Seller' => "Apple",
    'Product' => "<img src='Bild_MacBookAir.JPG' alt='MacBook Air' width='130px' />",
    'Price' => 999,
    'Selection' => "Mark3"
);
```

I dont know now exactly how to put the parameters in a function.
I tried already a lot of possibilities, but nothin is working.
It should be possible to make requests with forms.

Can you please help me? Thanks a lot!
Greets, Mikra

Comment: `function MyFunction(array $product){ // your code }`

Comment: function functionName($product) { //TODO:////}    click on link: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

But I have compensate my arrays with a function. So I have to put the parameters like category, product, seller, price etc. in a function. the details oft the array should be set then in the function.

And that is my problem... :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass and access the array variable using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648075/how-to-pass-and-access-the-array-variable-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your problem. You could pass the whole multi-dimensional array to a function the same way, you pass a one-dimensional array.

```
$products = [];
$products[] = [
    'Category' => "Smartphone",
    'Seller' => "Apple",
    'Product' => "<img src='Bild_iPhone_8.JPG' alt='iPhone 8' height='130px' />",
    'Price' => 836,
    'Selection' => "Mark1"
];
// ... add more products

processProducts($products);
```

and later in your code

```
function processProducts($products) {
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        processProduct($product['Category'], $product['Seller'], and so on...);
        // or..
        processProduct($product);
    }
}

function processProduct($category, $seller, ...) {

}
```

or

```
function processProduct($product) {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Array.push to insert multiple items to single array.

```
$product = array();
$item = array(
    'Category' => "Smartphone",
    'Seller' => "Apple",
    'Product' => "<img src='Bild_iPhone_8.JPG' alt='iPhone 8' height='130px' />",
    'Price' => 836,
    'Selection' => "Mark1"
);

array_push($product,$item);

print_r($product);
```

and then you can pass the main `$product` array to any function.

```
calculatePrice($product);
```

To access first element use `$product[0]` or use `foreach`  to loop over all.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 

But I need to create a new function as "function xxx()". I am not allowed to use already existent functions as array_push... :(